# Text to be clipping mask of Div background

Tags: javascript, html, css, mask, clipping

Bear with me on this... little hard to explain. So what I'm attempting to do is have a block of text remove the background of a div directly behind it. The image linked below was done is Illustrator and now I'm trying to find a solution within HTML & CSS.

[Illustrator screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIpMr.png)

```css
.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.grid-container img {
  position: absolute;
}

.grid-item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200/?random">
    <div class="grid-item-overlay">
      <span>Text Here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The objective is to have the span text create a transparent mask of the grid-item-overlay background.

I'm open to any suggestions! :)

Comment: But... are you in trouble or just want us to solve it for you?

Comment: Yes, trying to find a solution to the image attached.

Comment: I think you want us to "Bear with" you. [Baring with you is completely different](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1269)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try working with mix-blend-mode,

> mix-blend-mode : The mix-blend-mode CSS property describes how an
>   element's content should blend with the content of the element's
>   direct parent and the element's background.

```css
.grid-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.grid-container img {
  position: absolute;
}

.grid-item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200/?random">
    <div class="grid-item-overlay">
      <span>Text Here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just be aware that such a technology is still highly experimental as of right now. However, this is exactly what OP is looking for, and there's no other way to do such a thing.

Comment: @AntoineCombes well there might be, but I don't know. At-present this works fine.

Comment: There isn't. This is precisely for such use case (among others, of course) that blending modes are being introduced to CSS

Comment: Thank's so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome @Ross :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="grid-item">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200/?random">
    <div class="grid-item-overlay">
      <span class="text">Text Here</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add this css to your css File

```
    .text{
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
       }

 .grid-item-overlay:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:" ";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: block;
  z-index:0;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: But this won't remove the background of the div (.grid-item-overlay)